# Recent material (papers, books, etc) about Developmental Orthography

Tags: orthography, references

I have made a quick search on the internet about Developmental Orthography, but the papers and research projects I found are not very recent, some almost 20 years old. Apart from that almost all of them are about second language acquisition (English).
I am not quiet experience in the linguisic field really, so can you give a references of works about this topic?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think there is recent research in this topic? Developmental orthographies are strictly crutches that have not been proven to support anyone. If you want a developmental orthography, use [the one in Kenyon and Knott](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf), which can be used profitably even after literacy has set in.

Comment: I thought that with the recent focus on low-resourced languages, and the fact that the major part of these languages are **indigenous** with non-standardized orthographies (**naïve/native orthographies**); developmental orthography had made some advances.

Comment: Most indigenous languages don't have orthographies of any sort; those that do usually have phonemic orthographies, developed by linguists, for the most part. It's the languages where the orthography hasn't changed in centuries (like English) where there's a bad match of writing to sound.